# Sending email to localhost's parent domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I have iRedMail installed on a Ubuntu LTS 12.04. The mail server is at mail.domain.com

When trying to send email with SMTP authenticated using msmtp, I get this error:

```
msmtp: recipient address someone@domain.com not accepted by the server
msmtp: server message: 554 5.7.1 <someone@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected: Invalid HELO/EHLO; Must be a FQDN or an address literal, not 'localhost'
msmtp: could not send mail (account something from /etc/msmtprc)
```

My postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 4h
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 0h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = no
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 4h
message_size_limit = 15728640
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, localhost.$myhostname
mydomain = mail.domain.com
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = mail.domain.com
proxy_read_maps = $canonical_maps $lmtp_generic_maps $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $mynetworks $recipient_bcc_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relay_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relocated_maps $sender_bcc_maps $sender_canonical_maps $smtp_generic_maps $smtpd_sender_login_maps $transport_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $smtpd_sender_restrictions
queue_run_delay = 300s
readme_directory = no
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/recipient_bcc_maps_domain.cf
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/relay_domains.cf
relayhost =
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_bcc_maps_domain.cf
smtp-amavis_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtp_data_init_timeout = 240s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, check_helo_access pcre:/etc/postfix/helo_access.pcre
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = ./dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender_login_maps.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_sender_login_mismatch, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/iRedMail_CA.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/iRedMail.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
swap_bangpath = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_user.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/transport_maps_domain.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/catchall_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/domain_alias_catchall_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
```

I have domain.com email hosted in Google Apps, and do not want to use that in this server. Just use mail.domain.com as email server.

/etc/hosts does not have domain.com in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` is out of order. Its values are evaluated in sequence, so the order matters.

It currently looks like:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
```

You need to have `permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated` appear at the beginning, so that local mail and authenticated users do not have to go through checks that don't make sense for them.

So to fix it, move them to the beginning:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unlisted_recipient, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:7777, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031, reject
```